# Перенос строк в Python3 тип bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Во втором питоне можно написать строку вида

```
s ="\x31\xc9\xf7\xe1\x64\x8b\x41\x30\x8b\x40"\
"\x0c\x8b\x70\x14\xad\x96\xad\x8b\x58\x10"\
```

и будет работать. Как можно сделать аналогичную мульти-строчную строку для массива байт? Т.е. для

```
s = b'\x31\xc9\xf7\xe1\x64\x8b\x41\x30\x8b\x40'..
```

Если я пишу две строки подряд, оно не работает. Если задать через ''' тройные кавычки - в строку байт попадают символы переноса строки (что неприемлемо). Вариант только в одну строку, но это сильно растягивает редактор..

Answer (score 2):

Правила такие же как и для строк:

- Используйте `\`, чтобы экранировать перенос строки в коде
- Или объявляете в круглых скобках

Пример:

```
b = b'\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82' \
    b' \xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80!'
print(b.decode('utf-8'))
# привет мир!

b = (b'\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'
     b' \xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80!')
print(b.decode('utf-8'))
# привет мир!
```